# Conditional within a conditional

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to put a conditional statement within a conditional statement (something i thought was simple) in my code.

What is want is if `weekState` (boolean) is true, and `bool` is true, show the first jsx element. If `weekState` is true and `bool` is false, show the second jsx element. If `weekState` is false, return `null`. Semms pretty simple, but im obviously missing something.

```
       { weekState ?
           { bool ?
               <TableRow>
                   {take(weekListForAllAdvisorsOfState, 14)}
               </TableRow>
               :
               <TableRow>
                   {take(weekListForAllAdvisorsOfState, 7)}
               </TableRow> 
           }
            : null
       }
```

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234332/conditional-rendering-in-react-jscondition-inside-one-more-condition), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470607/problems-with-react-js-conditional-statement-within-another-conditional-statemen) which should have solved my issue, and makes me think theres a syntax error im not seeing.

The error im getting is
[image]

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: sorry @thedude, i added the error message above. forgot.

Comment: Is this the answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312122/how-to-do-a-nested-if-else-statement-in-reactjs-jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pair of unnecessary curly braces in the expression after `?`. Either remove them, or change them for parentheses `()`:

```
{weekState ? (
  bool ? (
    <TableRow>{take(weekListForAllAdvisorsOfState, 14)}</TableRow>
  ) : (
    <TableRow>{take(weekListForAllAdvisorsOfState, 7)}</TableRow>
  )
) : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think adding a Fragment should fix this:

```
{ weekState ?
        <React.Fragment>
           { bool ?
               <TableRow>
                   {take(weekListForAllAdvisorsOfState, 14)}
               </TableRow>
               :
               <TableRow>
                   {take(weekListForAllAdvisorsOfState, 7)}
               </TableRow> 
           }
            
          </React.Fragment>
          : null
       }
```